# Discord.py, client.get_all_members() not work

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

client= commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for a in client.get_all_members():
        time.sleep(1)
        print(a)
```

this code gave me the members of the server before, allowed me to create DM for members, but a few days ago it stopped working, only print me the bot name now.

Answer (score 0):

This was changed a few weeks ago. Check out `intents`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/intents.html